# msbuild not able to write to files

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to create a build process using cruise control 1.8.5.0 with TFS 2010 running on a windows server 2008 R2 machine.  The problem I'm running into is when MS Build is trying to write to files that ere just copied into the projects area it gets access denied. When I look at the files they are set to read only, the account that ccnet is running as is an admin on the box and everything is reading and writing locally.  We have a similar environment setup on Windows Server 2003 and everything works just fine.  We've verified that the account that is running the process is correct, I've set the owner of the projects folder to the same account that is running the process, we've disabled UAC.  At this point I'm at a loss. Any additional information needed let me know.

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//When I look at the files they are set to read only, //

You can run the attrib to remove the read-only flag on the files.

quick example:

```
<Exec Command=“attrib -R $(SolutionRoot)\MyCoolFile.txt“ />
```

There is also a custom task:

```
 <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksLib)" TaskName="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib" />
```

I've not used it, but that would be enough to hunt it down.

I'd guess it would look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Files Include="$(SolutionRoot)\MySubFolder\**\*.*/>
</ItemGroup>

<Attrib Files="%(Files.Identity)" ReadOnly="true"/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is happening during the MSbuild process, I'm assuming the Exec command would be run before or after the process is complete and it wouldn't catch the issue?  Is that correct or would I run this in a different manner?  I can post my build task if you want?

Comment: You just have to jam into your master msbuild (.proj) script the stuff above...right before the issue occurs..... Its one of those "it shouldn't happen, but it does".  I had this happen sometime in my msbuild past......which is why I responded.